# Which boost class should I use to store a human age

Tags: c++, boost

I have to store an age (years, months, days....possibly hours, minutes, seconds) of the user. I'm working with C++ and boost.

I'm not sure wich class of `boost::posix_time` (or `boost::date_time`) I should use.

I tried `boost::posix_time::time_duration`, but it's not obvious because there is no constructor taking a year count, it's only hours, so I did:

```
boost::posix_time::time_duration age = boost::posix_time::hours(24*365*ageInYears);
```

But I'm not sure that's a good strategy because all years does not have 365 days ;-)

I also tried `boost::gregorian::date`, but that's tricky because this one does not allow to store a `year` before 1400 (and this stores a date, not a duration).

- I don't want to store user date of birth because I need to store its age when my program ran (medical data).
- I don't want to store a regular `int` because it's not accurate enough (24 years old + 11 months is almost 25).
- I don't want to store a `float` because I don't want to reinvent the wheel with float to age conversion I would have to do...

Is there really no class making it easy to store a number of years and optionally a number of month and days in boost?

Ideally, for a guy of 30 years old and a half, I'd like to be able to create an object like that: `boost::....... theAge( 30, 6, 0 );` and then:

- Have a function to get age in years: theAge.years() returning 30 (ignoring months)
- Possibly have a conversion to float that would give me 30.5 as an age

Comment: "I don't want to store user date of birth" So calculate the difference (current_time - date_of_birth) as `boost::posix_time::time_duration`. I don't think 1400 is a real limitation for a medical program.

Comment: Problem is that I don't actually know patient date of birth....doctor enters directly an age as input.

Comment: If the doctor enters an age, calculate a DOB from that.

Comment: If the only thing you have is age in years as entered by the doctor, just use age_in_years * 365.25 * 24. The age in years is normally rounded down to the nearest year anyway (or to a month for very small children), so an error you introduce (if there is an error at all) is totally insignificant.

Comment: @jpo38 I know you explicitly asked about boost, but I want to point to an alternative library for date handling: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html. Depending on your needs, this may be a better alternative, e.g. when you have to handle time zones or leap seconds (then in conjunction with https://howardhinnant.github.io/tz.html).

Comment: @Jens: Nice alternative. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are indeed duration types in `boost::gregorian`, specifically:

- [`boost::gregorian::date_duration`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_time.gregorian.date_duration) (aka `boost::gregorian::days`) - a count of days
- [`boost::gregorian::months`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#additional_duration_types) - a count of calendar months
- `boost::gregorian::years` - a count of calendar years
- `boost::gregorian::weeks` - a count of 7 days

These would be ideal for storage i.e. store a tuple of (years, months, days).

Note though that arithmetic using in particular `months` and `years` can have unexpected results, as they provide a snap-to-end-of-month behavior:

```
months single(1); // 1 month duration
date(2005,Feb,28) + single; // => 2005-Mar-31
```

**Edit from OP owner:** There's actually a an existing boost struct to store year/month/day objects (`boost::date_time::date_time::year_month_day_base`).

Here is an implementation perfect to answer the OP:

```
class age : public date_time::year_month_day_base<years, months, days>
{
    typedef date_time::year_month_day_base<years, months, days> baseClass;
public:
    age( int yearsCount, int monthsCount = 0, int daysCount = 0 ) : 
        baseClass( boost::gregorian::years(yearsCount), 
                   boost::gregorian::months(monthsCount), 
                   boost::gregorian::days(daysCount) )
    {
    }

    inline int years() const { return year.number_of_years().as_number(); }
    inline int months() const { return month.number_of_months().as_number(); }
    inline int days() const { return day.days(); }

    float getAsFloat() const
    {
        float age = static_cast<float>(years());
        age += months()/12.0f;
        age += days()/365.25f;
        return age;
    }
};
```

Then, `age(30).years() == 30` and `age(30,6,8).getAsFloat() == 30.521902`

Comment: Unfortunately, this has the same limitation as using `boost::gregorian::date` as `boost::gregorian::years` rejects any value < 1400.....

Comment: @jpo38 How exactly are you trying to use `boost::gregorian::years`? It should work fine: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/478a0aa295da1c5a

Comment: I tried `boost::gregorian::greg_year_month_day patientAge(30,0,0);` This asserts because year must be > 1400 and also because month must be 1..12 and day must be 1..31. So I should use `boost::gregorian::greg_year_month_day patientAge(1430,1,1);` to code a 30 years old age....not very convenient.

Comment: @jpo38 I'm not suggesting to use `boost::gregorian::greg_year_month_day`, I'm suggesting `boost::gregorian::years`, `boost::gregorian::months` and `boost::gregorian::days` - note the plural.

Comment: I edited your post with the final class I wrote with your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`boost::posix_time::time_duration` really is one way to do this properly.  Another way (which I personally would prefer) is to store the birth date and the "as-of date" both, and subtract them when you need to find the age as-of that date.

In any case you don't need a constructor taking a number of years--you can simply subtract birth_date from today--if you do that using date_time objects, you'll get a time_duration.